# って部分 meaning and sentence translation

Tags: translation

Two people are discussing countermeasures for some new technology (Tech A) and what should be researched, issues and like. There is a lot of technobabble basically. The last possible solution is nowhere near ready and then the following exchange happens:

> M: Technology Bをヒントにした / 機構そのものはいい感じなんだけどねぇ
>
> H: 拡散してしまうなら / 高密度に圧縮した弾なり装置なりを利用すればいいって部分ですね。　ただ…

Technology B is something they got examples of recently and have been studying it. It's not what the countermeasures are for. Also I have used / to note word bubble splits, since it's a manga conversation and hence it has no punctuation (what fun).

The main problem I have with is the last line. The first one I think I have figured out, although I would appreciate being notified if I made some big mistake there.

> M: I do feel positive about the mechanism the Technology B hinted at.
>
> H: If it proliferates, it’s the part where we should use the devices or high density compressed bullets. However…

The second one is problematic for couple of reasons. First, the 拡散してしまうなら bit, I'm not sure what it refers to. I think it's a conditional "If Tech A proliferates/spreads".

The next problem I have is the って部分 bit, which is kinda strange. The only way I can figure it working is that M and H have had a conversation about possibilities of promising Technology B before and she is now referring to one part of that promise that M told H about.

What is weird to me is using a should (if we use it would be good) quote to describe a part? Which is why I'd like some input on what others think is the meaning of these lines.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you've understood the sentence correctly, and also understand the basics of the って grammar.

The って can mean multiple things including "speaking/talking of", but I think in this case it's a contraction of `という`.

> 高密度に圧縮した弾なり装置なりを利用すればいい**という**部分ですね。

Like this, it would translate like "the part where (described as) we should use the devices or high density..."

Answer (score 0):

I think 'って' is just a filler in this case, and omitting it does not change the meaning at all:

> 高密度に圧縮した弾なり装置なりを利用すればいい部分ですね。

Then, while いい is kind of an equivocal word, in this case いい部分 can be paraphrased as 解決できる部分:

> 高密度に圧縮した弾なり装置なりを利用すれば解決できる部分ですね。

So I'd translate it to "... where we can solve/resolve/fix with the devices or high density compressed bullet."