# What is 振らな駄目 supposed to mean. Possible typo in the original

Tags: translation

Continuation of the conversation from a [previous question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/58563/%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E9%83%A8%E5%88%86-meaning-and-sentence-translation).

In short characters are technobabble and following line happens.

> 撃鉄起こすのと出力コントロールに相当なresourceを振らな駄目ですからねぇ

The bit before 振らな I think means something along the lines of:

> Because when firing hammer is cocked, (in/for depending on verb) output control, significant "resource"...

Well I'm not sure if 相当な is significant or maybe appropriate, so it's resource appropriate to output control. But what mostly and completely baffles me is 振らな. I'm thinking this is probably some sort of typo (no I did not make a mistake typing this over)? And 駄目 used as a suffix to say whatever the verb was supposed to say is useless.

If it's a typo, it's likely that い is missing. Although then we kinda have a double negative, so I'd say it's then more of an imperative?

But yeah, the entire 振らな駄目です bit is utterly dumbfounding to me.

If it's relevant (I don't think it is), the person speaking could be a Kansai user (H is but M is not, and due to the format it could be either of them).

So what is your thinking on this conundrum of mine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's Kansai dialect for 振らないと. Here in Kansai we daily say things like:

> やらないとダメ/いけない → やらなダメ/アカン "have to do"
>   行かないとダメ/いけない → 行かなダメ/アカン "have to go"

So 振らな駄目 in your example means 振らないと駄目 / 振らないといけない, "have to/need to allocate".

---

> I'm not sure if 相当な is significant or maybe appropriate

相当な means "significant" here.

You can parse the sentence this way:

> ［撃鉄起こすの(=撃鉄を起こすこと)］と［出力コントロール］に相当なresourceを振らな駄目ですからねぇ

"(Since / We should note that) We (will) need to allocate significant resource to ［cocking/setting the gun hammer］ and ［output control］."

Comment: Well, that makes sense. Allthough it's kinda suprising Kansai would use ない I thought that dialect was all about へん.